# Laravel - How to extract value from json in my Laravel code

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

In my **Laravel-5.8**, I passed data from controller to view using JSON.

I am using Laravel-5.8 for a web application project.

I am trying to make my dropdown load value on a textbox on change.

```
public function findScore(Request $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;

    $identities                     = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();     
    $child  = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id',$request->id)->first();
    $parentid  = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('parent_id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id',$request->id)->first();
   if(empty($child))
   {
       abort(404);
   }  
   $weightedscore = DB::table('appraisal_goals')->select(DB::raw("SUM(weighted_score) as weighted_score"))->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities)->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('parent_id', $parentid)->get();
    $maxscore = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('max_score')->find($child->parent_id);
    return response()->json([
        'maxscore' => $maxscore->max_score,
        'weightedscore' => $weightedscore
    ]);        
}
```

I send the max_score and weighted_score as JSON.

route:

> Route::get('get/findScore','Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@findScore')->name('get.scores.all'); view blade

```
 <form  action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {{csrf_field()}}

<div class="card-body">
<div class="form-body">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">
    <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

    @foreach ($categories as $category)
    @unless($category->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
      <option hidden value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

      @if ($category->children)
        @foreach ($category->children as $child)
        @unless($child->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
          <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
        @endunless
        @endforeach
      @endif
      @endunless
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
</div>    

<input type="text" id="max_score"  class="form-control" >
<input type="text" id="weighted_score"  class="form-control" >

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#goal_type', function() {
        var air_id =  $(this).val();

        var a = $(this).parent();

        console.log("Its Change !");

        var op = "";



        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{{ route('get.scores.all') }}',
            data: { 'id': air_id },
            dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
            success: function(data) {
                // console.log("price");
                console.log(data.maxscore);
                console.log(data.weightedscore);
                 $('#max_score').val(data.maxscore);
                 $('#weighted_score').val(data.weightedscore);
            },
            error:function(){

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click on the dropdown on change the max_score is working perfectly, but the weighted_score is having error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/peopleedge/get/findScore?id=2 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

Then I got this on my console:

[image: weighted error]

and the textbox:

[image: textbox error]

I need the direct value to be displayed on the text and not the JSON object as shown in the diagram. For example, only 60 in the textbox.

How do I get this resolved?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running your code using `php artisan`? If yes, what is displayed in the command line after opening the failing URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$weightedscore` is an object, so you should do the same for `$weightedscore` what you do for `$maxscore`: add the attribute and not the object to the response.

Change `$weightedscore` to `$weightedscore->weighted_score` in the `return` part.

```php
return response()->json([
    'maxscore' => $maxscore->max_score,
    'weightedscore' => $weightedscore->weighted_score
]);
```

You can output `$weightedscore` before returning it by using `var_dump($weightedscore);` or `print_r($weightedscore);` and then you will see that it is an object having an attribute called `weighted_score` as stated in your `SELECT ... as()` part of your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

since it is array hence it will be

$('#max_score').val(data.maxscore['maxscore']);
$('#weighted_score').val(data.weightedscore['weightedscore'][0]);

['weightedscore']=keyname that you gave on the controller

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{{ route('get.scores.all') }}',
                data: { 'id': air_id },
                dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                success: function(data) {
                    // console.log("price");
                    console.log(data.maxscore);
                    console.log(data.weightedscore);
                     $('#max_score').val(data.maxscore['maxscore']);
                     $('#weighted_score').val(data.weightedscore['weightedscore'][0]);



                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
```

Comment: Your solution may work, but I argue it is a better practice to change the data format where it is produced and not where it is consumed if you are able to do soe. Furthermore, the structure is not consistent because the @mikefolu is returning one value as object and one as primitive type.

Comment: @Johannes let's give the authority to the question owner to chose/judge what he/she feels right . I am here just sharing what I know and help him/her. One problem have multi solutions.

Comment: Nothing is displayed

Comment: Yes, of course. I never said that you solution is not correct or that it should not be used, I just wanted to give a recommendation.